# Which SDK should I use to build the project with Support Library?

Tags: android

I'm not sure which SDK version should I use to build the project if I added a Support Library. Shouldn't I build it with 2.3.3 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter which version of the Platform you are using with the Support Library.

The Support Library is designed to back-port some important new features from Android (like Fragments), so they are supported in older versions of the OS (back to 1.6).

Bottom line, you can use any version of the SDK with the support library (all the way back to 1.6).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the support library in API level 4 and above, so you can build it against pretty much whatever version your other APIs require.